# Trigonometry - $\sin \alpha$, if $\tan 4\alpha =\sqrt{15}$ and $180^\circ < \alpha <224^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\sin \alpha$, if $\tan 4\alpha =\sqrt{15}$ and $180^\circ < \alpha <224^\circ$.

Please help if someone can solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you aware of the multiple angle formulae?

Comment: I'm new to Trigonometry so I've tried reduce formulas to reduce to 2α and then the equation was too confusing.

Comment: By the way is $224$ supposed to be $225$?  It doesn't make any practical difference but $225 = 180 + 45$ and $45$ is an eighth of a circle.  (Which tells you that $\sin \alpha$ is positive)

Comment: No, it's 180<α<224

Comment: I'm a bit surprised of the number of answers for a homework question as the OP didn't show *any* work.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe it's quite a tricky question, although the methods are elementary. For example, the accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $\tan 4\alpha = \frac {\sin 4\alpha}{\cos 4\alpha} =\sqrt {15}$ we have

$\sin 4\alpha = \sqrt {15}\cos \alpha$ and $1=\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 4\alpha = 15\cos^2 4\alpha + \cos^2 4\alpha = 16\cos^2 4\alpha$.  So $cos^2 4\alpha = \frac 1{16}$ and $\sin^2 4\alpha = \frac {15}{16}$.

so $\sin 4\alpha =\pm \frac {\sqrt {15}}4$.  And as $180< \alpha < 224$ then $720=2*360  < 4\alpha < 896 = 2*360 + 176$.  $\sin 4\alpha$ is positive and $\sin 4\alpha = \frac {\sqrt {15}}4$.

Okay..... $\cos 4\alpha = \cos(2\alpha + 2\alpha)= \cos2\alpha \cos2\alpha - \sin 2\alpha \sin 2\alpha= \cos^2 2\alpha - \sin^2 2\alpha=1-2\sin^2 \alpha = \frac {\sqrt{15}}4$.

So $\sin 2 \alpha =\pm\sqrt {\frac {4-\sqrt{15}}8}$

And $360 < 2\alpha < 360 + 88$ so $\sin 2\alpha$ is positive.

We also know $\cos 2\alpha$ is positive and $\cos 2\alpha = \sqrt{1-\frac {4-\sqrt{15}}8}=\sqrt{\frac {4-\sqrt {15}}{8}}$

And $\cos 2\alpha = \cos^2 \alpha - \sin^2 \alpha = 1-2\sin^2 \alpha = \sqrt{\frac {4-\sqrt {15}}{8}}$

$2\sin^2 \alpha = 1-\sqrt{\frac {4-\sqrt {15}}{8}}$

$\sin \alpha= \pm \sqrt{\frac { 1-\sqrt{\frac {4-\sqrt {15}}{8}}}2}$

ANd as $180 < \alpha < 224$ we know $\sin \alpha$ is negative.

So once you fix the arithmetic errors that I inevetiably always make you will have the answer

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I think the value for $\sin 2\alpha$ is wrong. This is because you substitute the value for sin4a instead of cos4a in the calculation. See my answer please.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check the valid range of the $\alpha$ first.
Since $\alpha \in (180^\circ,224^\circ)$,
the range of $4\alpha$ spans from $4\cdot180^\circ=0^\circ \mod 360^\circ$
to $(224^\circ-180^\circ)\cdot 4=176^\circ$,
that is, it includes
whole $\textsf I$ quadrant
and part of $\textsf{II}$ quadrant.

But we know that $\tan4\alpha>0$,
so we can cut the range of $4\alpha$
to
$(4\cdot180^\circ, 4\cdot180^\circ+90^\circ)$,
and hence we can shrink the range of $\alpha$ to
$(180^\circ, 180^\circ+22.5^\circ)$
$=(180^\circ,202.5^\circ)$
and we can also conclude that
$2\alpha\in(360^\circ,405^\circ)=(0^\circ,45^\circ) \mod 360^\circ$,
that is, we must have $2\alpha$ in the first quadrant,
and $\tan2\alpha>0$.

Down-grading the angle $4\alpha$ to $2\alpha$,
we get
\begin{align}
\tan4\alpha&=
\frac{2\tan 2\alpha}{1-\tan^2 2\alpha}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

which gives two possible expressions for the value of $\tan2\alpha$:

\begin{align}
\tan2\alpha
&=
\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+\tan^24\alpha}}{\tan4\alpha}
=-\tfrac13\,\sqrt{15}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\tan2\alpha
&=
\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+\tan^24\alpha}}{\tan4\alpha}
=\tfrac15\,\sqrt{15}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}
so we can discard the negative one
and conclude that
$\tan2\alpha=\tfrac15\,\sqrt{15}$.

Repeating the down-grading further,
we get
\begin{align}
\tan2\alpha&=
\frac{2\tan \alpha}{1-\tan^2 \alpha}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}

again with two possible roots

\begin{align}
\tan\alpha
&=
\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+\tan^2 2\alpha}}{\tan2\alpha}
=-\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,(2\,\sqrt2+\sqrt5)
\approx -2.92
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\tan\alpha
&=
\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+\tan^2 2\alpha}}{\tan 2\alpha}
=\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,(2\sqrt2-\sqrt5)
\approx 0.34
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Again, we must choose the positive root,
and continue with
$\tan\alpha=\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,(2\sqrt2-\sqrt5)$,
considering that $\alpha$ is in the $\textsf{III}$
quadrant and $\sin\alpha<0$,
\begin{align}
\sin\alpha&=
-\frac{\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}}
=-\tfrac14\,\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{10}}
\approx -0.323597
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You might think that there’s very little information. However, knowing the tan immediately gives us the sin and the cos. The trick is to draw a relevant triangle and find out this extra information.

You have to use the condition on the angle so that you don’t get a lot of possible cases.

I didn’t finish the question, but hopefully you get the idea and can do the exact same thing to finish it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you!!!